# Find some probabilities given the probability tree

Tags: probability, problem-solving

i've been practicing probability since it's not my strength, but i am doing that without a tutor or an official course, just books and videos. I was reading a problem, and i was capable of draw the Probability tree (The event and its probability given the parent branch), can you help me to find out the following probabilities, thank you very much!!

[image]

a. $P(P)$

b. $P(G)$

c. $P(B | \neg P) = P(B | NP)$

d. $P(G | P)$

e. $P(C | G)$

I guess i would need to apply the total probability theorem and Bayes Rule, but i want to supervise my steps.
Thank you again.

Comment: Also add to the question what you have done allready.

Answer (score 3):

a) $P(P) = P(P\;\cap\;A)+P(P\;\cap\;B)+P(P\;\cap\;C)$
$\quad \quad \quad = (0.25)(0.4)+(0.45)(0.2)+(0.3)(0.3) = 0.28$

b) $P(G)=P(A\;\cap\;P\; \cap G)+P(A\;\cap\;NP\; \cap G)$
   $\quad \quad \quad \quad + P(B\;\cap\;P\; \cap\;G) + P(B\;\cap\;NP\;\cap\;G) $
$\quad \quad \quad \quad + P(C\;\cap\;P\; \cap\;G)+P(C\;\cap\;NP\;\cap\;G)$

$\quad \quad \quad = (0.25)(0.4)(0.85) + (0.25)(0.6)(0.2) $
$\quad\quad\quad \;\; + (0.45)(0.2)(0.65) + (0.45)(0.8)(0.1) $
$\quad\quad\quad\;\;  + (0.3)(0.3)(0.1) + (0.3)(0.7)(0.3)$

$\quad\quad\quad = 0.2815$

c) $P(NP) = P(NP\;\cap\;A) + P(NP\;\cap\;B) + P(NP\;\cap\;C)$
   $\quad \quad\quad\quad \quad = (0.6)(0.25) + (0.8)(0.45) + (0.7)(0.3)$
   $\quad\quad\quad \quad\quad= 0.72$

$\quad P(B|NP)=\frac{P(B \;\cap\; NP)}{P(NP)} = \frac{(0.45)(0.8)}{0.72}$

d) $P(G|P)=\frac{P(G\;\cap\;P)}{P(P)}= \frac{P(G\;\cap\;P\;\cap\;A)+P(G\;\cap\;P\;\cap\;B)+P(G\;\cap\;P\;\cap\;C)}{P(P)}$
$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad =\frac{(0.25)(0.4)(0.85) + (0.45)(0.2)(0.65) + (0.3)(0.3)(0.9)}{0.28}$

e) $P(C|G)=\frac{P(C\;\cap\;G)}{P(G)}$
$\quad\quad\quad\quad\;\; =\frac{P(C\;\cap\;G\;\cap\;P) + P(C\;\cap\;G\;\cap\;NP)}{P(G)}$
$\quad\quad\quad\quad\;\; = \frac{(0.3)(0.3)(0.9)+(0.3)(0.7)(0.3)}{0.2815}$